# How to clean the Android Recent App List

Tags: android, android-recents

I'm looking for a way to clean the android recent app list programmatically. 
The list which pop up when the "2 superposed boxes" button is pressed.

Has anyone a idea or hint for me, how can I do this ?

The background is, I develop a little app and one requirement is, in "safe mode" the list must be empty. My idea is to clean the list on shutdown.

Thanks,
André

Comment: It is not possible to remove apps that you do not own from that list

Comment: That sounds like an extremely bad user experience. The user might have important things going on in the running apps. Closing them programmatically is very rude.

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this?  What's the point?

Comment: I think you're looking for http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude why would you care if other apps are in the recent list as long as yours isn't?

Comment: With Android 5 Apps in the hone screen can be startet in safe mode, that sucks. So i develop a small app which modified the Shortcuts and avoid the launching in Safe Mode. But the Apps can be startet from the recent List. This sucks

Answer (score 0):

Just for your curiosity yeah its possible, But It's a very bad decision since the user might not want his/her important task to be killed.

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();
    //get a list of installed apps.
    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

   for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;
        if(packageInfo.packageName.equals("mypackage")) continue;
        mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);
   }
```

Comment: While this will kill the apps, I'm not convinced that you'll remove them reliably from the recents list.

Comment: No this doesn't work. The Apps are still in the recent Apps List.